# How to fix '(1<<100)*0.1 and (1<<100)/10'

Tags: go

In *A Tour of Go*, section *Numeric Constants*, the code is

```
package main

import "fmt"

const (
    // Create a huge number by shifting a 1 bit left 100 places.
    // In other words, the binary number that is 1 followed by 100 zeroes.
    Big = 1 << 100
    // Shift it right again 99 places, so we end up with 1<<1, or 2.
    Small = Big >> 99
)

func needInt(x int) int { return x*10 + 1 }

func needFloat(x float64) float64 { return x * 0.1 }

func main() {
    fmt.Println(needInt(Small))
    fmt.Println(needFloat(Small))
    fmt.Println(needFloat(Big))

    fmt.Println(Big * 0.1) //one
    fmt.Println(Big / 10)  //two
}
```

`fmt.Println(Big*0.1)` output `1.2676506002282295e+29`,
but `fmt.Println(Big / 10)` throw an error:`constant 126765060022822940149670320537 overflows int`,
what's difference between them.

Comment: Please read https://blog.golang.org/constants . Summing up: Constant can be arbitrary precision/large. But sometimes a constant must be converted to a real Go type. In your case a float and an int. Not every constant can be converted an this is a compile time error. The difference is: `Big*0.1` is converted to float while `Big/10` is converted to int. Details in the blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Go blog on [constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants):

> Numeric constants live in an arbitrary-precision numeric space; they
>   are just regular numbers. But when they are assigned to a variable the
>   value must be able to fit in the destination.

An example may make this clearer:

```
const f = 1 << 31

x := f / 10  // what type is x?
y := f * 0.1 // what type is y?

fmt.Printf(" 10 : type = %8T\n", 10)    // int
fmt.Printf("0.1 : type = %8T\n\n", 0.1) // float64

fmt.Printf(" x  : type = %8T  value = %v\n", x, x)
fmt.Printf(" y  : type = %8T  value = %v\n", y, y)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LH6xqrobKOB) output:

```
 10 : type =      int
0.1 : type =  float64

 x  : type =      int  value = 214748364
 y  : type =  float64  value = 2.147483648e+08
```

---

- `x` is an `int` since the devisor `10` is interpreted as an `int`.
- `y` is a `float64` since the multiplier `0.1` is interpreted as a `float64`.

In the tour example, the const is `1<<100`, which is too large to fit into an `int` (32-bits), so the program will fail to even compile, as the number cannot be stored into the allocated memory type: 100 bits will not fit into a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: Think you very much，i got it.

Comment: @joystrong if you like an answer to your question - don't forget to make it as "accepted" (click the checkmark) to close out the question.